# Right angle corners issue with Instances that follow Tangent Curve for Brick Wall with Geo Nodes

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, procedural, instances

I've created a brick wall using Geo Nodes, with instances from separate brick object. I've also used proximity to remove a portion of the wall for damage.

[image: Brick wall made with Geo Nodes]

Unfortunately the corners come out rounded and not squared off like a normal brick wall would.

[image: Odd brick wall corners]

I'm currently using a curve to define the shape of the brick layers and having the instances rotation follow the curve tangent. This seems to be what is creating the issue.

One thing I would like to note is that I realize that the corners of the curves do not look square either. This seems to come from the Resample Curve node I have at the beginning, but it was necessary as that was the only way to space out the bricks so they didn't overlap.

[image: Curve Layers]

Ideally, I would like it to not only be restricted to 90 degree angles, but also be able to include the use a half bricks (which I have also modeled) as caps to end the row if it comes up short.

[image: Bricks for the instances]

Here is my node tree (minus the nodes for the proximity brick removal for clarity as they are not part of the issue):

[image: Geo Nodes Node tree for brick wall]

I've tried everything and I just can't seem to get the right combination of nodes and math to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the technique you used, the corners would always appear strange, because by moving the curve points along the tangents, they would always protrude a bit.

In addition, you wouldn't be able to get a pattern together with these bricks where the bricks get alternating positions per row, because the dimensions aren't suitable for that.

To be exact, a stone would always have to be exactly half as wide as it is long, because at the corners the stones join at a $90°$ angle. The height is of course irrelevant.

I would therefore suggest the following solution:

[image]
[image]

Here I divide the curve into individual segments, instead of processing the curve as one element. If I move the points along the tangents, the further processing and selection is easier.

Instead of instantiating the base curve along a *Mesh Line*, I also use the node `Duplicate Elements`. This node then also provides me with an incremental index per row, which I can use directly for further calculations.

Note, however, that the length of a side must always be exactly divisible by the length of the brick, otherwise there will be gaps in the wall.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I needed. I've got it working on my wall and it looks great!

I'm still trying to reverse engineer it to make sure I understand how it works. I'm a little fuzzy on it but I think I get the gist of it. Geometry Nodes is still something I need a lot more practice at.

Comment: This is really great, thanks for providing the .blend too. I will try to improve this for 3d printing by adding more noisy positioning of bricks and also an internal mesh to ensure the wall is manifold.